# JDesktopPane has a toolbar at bottom of window on linux

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have a JDesktopPane that adds JInternalFrames. On Linux (ubuntu) and Mac os, all displayed internal frame appear in a taskbar/toolbar standing in the bottom left corner, with the name of each internal frame as label. This toolbar is not displayed on Windows, which is the behaviour I expect.

[image]

Would anybody know how to desactivate this toolbar?

I'm setting the internal frames this way:

```
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setClosable(false);
frame.setMaximizable(false);
frame.setIconifiable(false);
```

And adding them to `JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UIManager.put("DesktopPaneUI","javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDesktopPaneUI");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `removeAll()` on your JDesktopPanes after creating them.

Comment: hmm ... sounds counter-intuitive as the frames are added, to start with ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but anyhow that nasty bar has to be out before adding the frames ( Why Linux? :( ).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
frame.setIcon ( false );
```

This will force the frame to be shown.

It is possible that on Ubuntu/Mac those frames are iconified by default, that is why they appear in the corner of the JDesktopPane.

Comment: unfortunately it does not change anything, either when calling setIcon(false) before or after adding the internal frame to the desktop pane.

Answer (score 0):

This worked in my case:

```
UIManager.put("InternalFrame.useTaskBar", Boolean.FALSE);
```

It should be "less invasive" than replacing a whole UI class, and if you change to a Look and Feel that doesn't display the toolbar the property should be simply ignored